# SNMP monitoring using ELK Stack - similar to Zabbix

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, zabbix

I need to get the snmp monitoring details into ELK stack.

Can anyone give me a reference or guide me on how to do that.

Or is there an option to send the snmp monitoring data from Zabbix to ELK stack.

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. Is it sending raw data from polled SNMP? Raw data from SNMP traps? Data from Zabbix events?

Answer (score 0):

You can [write your own beat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/new-beat.html), which will read SNMP metrics from snmpd. It'll be IMHO nice and robust approach.

Or you can utilize Zabbix API a read data directly from the Zabbix - it'll be slower and you may have a problem with horizontal scaling if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Is there any solutions which is directly available.